# iphone sdk: NSCFString does not match with value

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, kinvey, nscfstring

I am using Kinvey Kit in one of my apps. While using query `+(KCSQuery *)queryOnField:(NSString *)field withExactMatchForValue:(NSObject *)value`, I try matching record with KCSUser userId. It does not match by using self.userId but if I do `@"53a7ded611324c8002041603"`, it matches immediately. self.userId is same as `53a7ded611324c8002041603` except its type is NSCFString.

Its driving me nuts. Is there anyway to change NSCFString to NSString.

Comment: An NSCFString **is** an NSString.  Are you using `==` to compare them?

Comment: No, I am using it this way KCSQuery *findInvited = [KCSQuery queryOnField:@"invited_id" withExactMatchForValue:self.userId];